# Linux user process spending 99% of time in kernel thread, no syscalls, still running but slowly

Tags: c++, linux-kernel, ubuntu-20.04

I have a process that is getting "stuck" in a loop of pure user code. Both `htop` and `time` show the process is spending most of it's time in the kernel, but it isn't making any syscalls.

This behavior only occurs on half of invocations. When it happens, the loop takes several minutes to run. When it does not happen, it takes less than a second.

`strace` shows no differences between a good and bad invocation, and only a few system calls are made by the allocator.

The code in question is a photogrammetry suite called AliceVision. The exact loop is here on github: https://github.com/alicevision/AliceVision/blob/develop/src/aliceVision/track/TracksBuilder.cpp#L89

```
  for(const IndexedFeaturePair& featPair: allFeatures)
  {
    lemon::ListDigraph::Node node = _d->graph.addNode();
    map_indexToNode.insert(std::make_pair(featPair, node));
    _d->map_nodeToIndex.insert(std::make_pair(node, featPair));
  }
```

This code is just building some stl and boost containers, and none of the called methods have any locking. `allFeatures` has about 9 million entries.

I've gone through all the usual debugging techniques, gdb call stacks look fine (there are two other threads from libgomp, but they are just sitting on a `FUTEX_WAIT` syscall). `perf` shows the same results regardless of whether it gets stuck in the kernel or not.

My remaining hunch is weird scheduler behaviour. The machine is a 16 core/32 thread Ryzen 1950x threadripper with 48GB ram running ubuntu 20.04, kernel 5.4.0-generic.

Playing with `nice` values seems to have no effect.

Ideas? Thank you.

### uname

```
uname -a
Linux snorlax 5.4.0-40-generic #44-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 23 00:01:04 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

### lscpu

```
lscpu
Architecture:                    x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:                      Little Endian
Address sizes:                   43 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
CPU(s):                          32
On-line CPU(s) list:             0-31
Thread(s) per core:              2
Core(s) per socket:              16
Socket(s):                       1
NUMA node(s):                    2
Vendor ID:                       AuthenticAMD
CPU family:                      23
Model:                           1
Model name:                      AMD Ryzen Threadripper 1950X 16-Core Processor
Stepping:                        1
Frequency boost:                 enabled
CPU MHz:                         1988.628
CPU max MHz:                     3400.0000
CPU min MHz:                     2200.0000
BogoMIPS:                        6786.43
Virtualization:                  AMD-V
L1d cache:                       512 KiB
L1i cache:                       1 MiB
L2 cache:                        8 MiB
L3 cache:                        32 MiB
NUMA node0 CPU(s):               0-7,16-23
NUMA node1 CPU(s):               8-15,24-31
Vulnerability Itlb multihit:     Not affected
Vulnerability L1tf:              Not affected
Vulnerability Mds:               Not affected
Vulnerability Meltdown:          Not affected
Vulnerability Spec store bypass: Mitigation; Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl and seccomp
Vulnerability Spectre v1:        Mitigation; usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization
Vulnerability Spectre v2:        Mitigation; Full AMD retpoline, STIBP disabled, RSB filling
Vulnerability Srbds:             Not affected
Vulnerability Tsx async abort:   Not affected
Flags:                           fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_op
                                 t pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc cpuid extd_apicid amd_dcm aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 fm
                                 a cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3d
                                 nowprefetch osvw skinit wdt tce topoext perfctr_core perfctr_nb bpext perfctr_llc mwaitx cpb hw_pstate sme ssbd sev vmmcall fs
                                 gsbase bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 rdseed adx smap clflushopt sha_ni xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves clzero irperf xsaveerptr arat npt 
                                 lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale vmcb_clean flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold avic v_vmsave_vmload vgif overf
                                 low_recov succor smca
```

### strace output

```
197475 mmap(NULL, 298352640, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ff476378000
197476 mmap(NULL, 298352640, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ff4646f0000
197477 write(2, "[09:14:30.993443][debug] all fea"..., 44) = 44
197478 write(2, "\n", 1)                       = 1
197479 brk(0x555b0d02d000)                     = 0x555b0d02d000
197480 brk(0x555b0d05d000)                     = 0x555b0d05d000
197481 mmap(NULL, 266240, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ff4a61e4000
197482 brk(0x555b0d01e000)                     = 0x555b0d01e000
197483 mmap(NULL, 528384, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ff4a6163000
197484 munmap(0x7ff4a61e4000, 266240)          = 0
197485 mmap(NULL, 1052672, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ff4a6062000
197486 munmap(0x7ff4a6163000, 528384)          = 0
197487 mmap(NULL, 2101248, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ff4a5e61000
197488 munmap(0x7ff4a6062000, 1052672)         = 0
197489 mmap(NULL, 4198400, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ff4a5a60000
197490 munmap(0x7ff4a5e61000, 2101248)         = 0
197491 mmap(NULL, 8392704, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ff4a525f000
197492 munmap(0x7ff4a5a60000, 4198400)         = 0
197493 mmap(NULL, 16781312, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ff4a425e000
197494 munmap(0x7ff4a525f000, 8392704)         = 0
197495 mmap(NULL, 33558528, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ff48dfff000
197496 munmap(0x7ff4a425e000, 16781312)        = 0
197497 mmap(NULL, 67112960, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ff4606ef000
197498 munmap(0x7ff48dfff000, 33558528)        = 0
197499 mmap(NULL, 134221824, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ff4586ee000
197500 munmap(0x7ff4606ef000, 67112960)        = 0
197501 mmap(NULL, 268439552, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ff4486ed000
197502 munmap(0x7ff4586ee000, 134221824)       = 0

# runs for several minutes
```

### htop

[image: htop output]

Comment: It is a problem on user program, not of linux kernel. And I assume it is just some bug about threats, multi-processor communication, locking, signals, etc. not so infrequent, but it is 99.9% problem of userspace (the rest is often hardware problem). You may discover why people hat threads and multiprocessing: difficult to debug, and bugs may appears only on certain conditions.

Comment: Have you tried profiling to find out where the time is spent exactly? Btw, syscalls might be called for memory allocation too (`_sbrk`).

Comment: It is fair that it is very likely a userspace problem. However, suggestions on how to debug why a thread can sit in the kernel without making syscalls would be appreciated.

Comment: I would check your library, if there is options to use only one thread, or without optimization. Or you need a debugger, and pause the process when it hang. Do it various times, check where it block, and what was the last function from your program that are in the stack. -- And maybe you should look in this site, searching "<library name> hang". With your tags. you will probably not find the right people to answer your question

Comment: I may be wrong, but to me this looks like a memory fragmentation issue. The program repeatedly requests bigger and bigger chunks of memory. In the trace the last request is for some 256MB. With time the memory which is managed by the kernel gets fragmented and the kernel may need to move/compact chunks of memory. `mmap()` would have to wait while that is done, hence the delays. If that's indeed what's happening, then it might be a good idea to rework the algorithm to use smaller pieces of memory.

Comment: `map_indexToNode` is declared `stl::flat_map`.  I think a change to `std::unordered_map` would likely improve performance.

Comment: Are you just thrashing?  That’s system time but doesn’t involve any system calls.